# Date in DB difference with result get in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, lumen

i have some table and there are column date
with value : 2021-07-01 10:00:00

when im fetching that, with ->get() or ->first() or anything of method in laravel to fetch data, i have difference result, look like the value has formated / converted to another timezone, but in laravel config or env , i dont set anything about configuration of timeszone, i has googling but not finding , can somebody tell me about this case, or maybe iam must be set some config to get proper value?

Comment: what is your SQL timezone set as

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to update your code.
1- open config/app.php and edit

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Here you can add your timezone like

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Tokyo',
```

If you want to manage your timezone from .env file you can use this code

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
```

and add the this line in your .env file.

```
APP_TIMEZONE='Asia/Tokyo'
```

Comment: not affected, iam still have difference value